# The collection of Borel sets $\mathcal{B}$ is dilation invariant

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, borel-sets

I have proved the following statement and I would like to know if I have made any mistakes, thank you.

"Prove that the collection of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{B}$, is dilation invariant. More precisely, prove that if $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a Borel set and $t\in\mathbb{R}$, then $tB:=\{tb:b\in B\}$ is a Borel set."

My proof:

*(EDIT: I now believe only the parts in bold are necessary for the proof)*

**If $t=0$ the claim is trivial ($0B=\{0\}$ which is a Borel set, since all countable sets are Borel)**. so in the following we assume $t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.

---

Let $t\in\mathbb{R}$: we now prove that $t\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra

$\emptyset\in\mathcal{B}$ and $\emptyset\overset{*}{=}t\emptyset\in t\mathcal{B}$

> *suppose for sake of contradiction that $t\emptyset\neq\emptyset$: this means there exists an element $a\in t\emptyset$ i.e. $a=to$, where $o\in\emptyset$, contradiction, since $\emptyset$ does not contain elements by definition.

$E\in t\mathcal{B}\Rightarrow E^c=tB^c, B^c\in\mathcal{B}$ so $E^c\in t\mathcal{B}$;

$E_1, E_2,\dots\in t\mathcal{B}\Rightarrow E_1=tB_1, E_2=tB_2, \dots\Rightarrow\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}tB_k=t\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k\in t\mathcal{B}$, since $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k\in\mathcal{B}$.

---

Now, let $O$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$: then it can be written as the countable union of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}, O=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_k,b_k)\in\mathcal{B}$ and if we set $t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ we can also write $O=t\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{t}a_k,\frac{1}{t} b_k)\in t\mathcal{B}$. So, $t\mathcal{B}$ contains every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and since by definition $\mathcal{B}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all the open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ it follows that $\mathcal{B}\subset t\mathcal{B}.$

---

**Now, let $t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, f(x):=\frac{1}{t}x$: then $f$, being a continuous function is also a Borel-measurable function so $f^{-1}(B)=tB$ is a Borel set for every Borel set $B$** so we also have that $t\mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{B}$ thus $t\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{B}$, **as desired.**

Comment: It seems overly long. If $t=0$ then $\{0\}$ is Borel. If $t \neq 0$ then $x \mapsto tx$ is a homeomorphism

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for your interest in my question. I imagined there would be a faster way to work through the proof but for starters I don't know what a homeomorphism is, and second, I am trying to stick to what instruments the book I am self-studying from (Axler's MIRA book) gives. That said, do you think that the proof is correct (even if longer than strictly necessary)? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by ${\cal B} \subset t + {\cal B}$?

Comment: @copper.hat that was a typo (now corrected) as it should be $t\mathcal{B}$, sorry!

Comment: homeomorphism means continuous with continuous inverse... which is pretty much what you're using in your last paragraph.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see, thank you.

Comment: The last paragraph can be used in both directions, since $x \mapsto to xt$ and $x \mapsto {1 \over t}x$ are both continuous.

Comment: @copper.hat If you'll write your comments as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @lorenzo Glad to be able to help.